# Can't add ImageIcon to JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I've been trying to add an image to a `JFrame` but I can't seem to get it done.

I looked at online tutorials and other similar questions but nothing seems to work.

```
ImageIcon wiz = new ImageIcon("wizard.png");
ImageIcon assassin = new ImageIcon("assassin.png");

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Select");
frame.setBounds(50, 50,1000, 1000);
JButton w = new JButton("Wizard");
JButton a = new JButton("Assasin");

JFrame f = new JFrame("Image");

JLabel img1 = new JLabel(wiz);

frame.setLayout(null);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setIconImage(wiz.getImage());

w.setBounds(30,380,100,60);
frame.add(w);

a.setBounds(200, 380, 100, 60);
frame.add(a);

f.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You add one `ImageIcon` to a `JLabel` but you don't add that `JLabel` to any of the frames.

Comment: I just did that but still nothing appears

Comment: Have you set `img1`'s bounds ?

Comment: would that be with .setBounds()?

Comment: Yes, just like for the other components.

Comment: img1.setBounds(200, 380, 100, 60);

Added this but still doesn't appear

Comment: Is your image called "wizard.png"? (Extension is important) Is it in the same folder? BTW Don't use `null-layout`

Comment: Do you want to set the icon of `JFrame` (shown in top left corner)? Or do you want to add the image to `JFrame`'s content area?

Comment: Right now I just want the image itself to appear in JFrame and will worry about the positioning once I can get it to appear

Comment: What @PrasadKarunagoda is saying is "You want to display the APP ICON (IconImage) or as an Image inside the area?"

Comment: Oh ok, I want to display it as an image inside the area

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I think I got it to work

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main problem in your program is that you try absolute positioning of components (e.g. `JLabel`) using `setLayout(null)` and `setBounds()` on components.

In Swing, the correct way to place components is by using layout managers. See this tutorial for details about how to use layout managers:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

As a sample program, I've successfully set images (both as `JFrame`'s icon and inside `JFrame`'s contents area) in below program. Try it and see.

This is a screenshot of my sample `JFrame`.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameWithIcon
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Since I'm not setting a layout manager to contentPane, it's default (BorderLayout) is used

    //This sets the image in JFrame's content area
    f.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("star.png")));

    //This sets JFrame's icon (shown in top left corner of JFrame)
    f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("star.png").getImage());

    f.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```